# Ionic 3: Property 'channel' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 to post some parameters to a URL and I receive the JSON below in return

```
{
channel: {
    id: 9164115,
    name: "STATION AT SA BI",
    description: "With DIC DIU",
    latitude: "0.0",
    longitude: "0.0",
    created_at: "2017-07-01T09:09:23+03:00",
    updated_at: "2018-01-22T01:52:04+03:00",
    last_entry_id: 498718
},
feeds: [
    {
        created_at: "2017-07-01T09:09:23+03:00",
        field2: "3.3088235294117645"
    },
    {
        created_at: "2017-07-01T09:09:23+03:00",
        field2: "3.736666666666667"
    },
    {
        created_at: "2017-07-01T09:09:23+03:00",
        field2: "3.9456666666666664"
    },
    {
        created_at: "2017-07-01T09:09:23+03:00",
        field2: "3.706521739130434"
    }
  ]
}
```

I read the JSON that is returned from the URL as below

```
var data = {'channel': '9164115', 'field': 'XJ' }    
try {
  this.restProvider.postData("http://apiurl.com/list", data).then((result) => {

    console.log(result); // DISPLAYS JSON IN CONSOLE
    this.last_updateDate = result.channel.updated_at; // FAILS

  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
} catch (e){
  console.log(e);
}
```

I am able to print out the JSON in my console and view it, but when I attempt to read its objects, I get this error.

```
Property 'channel' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

I have reviewed a couple of solutions online but none seems to work for my case.

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Declare the result as `(result:any)` and it will work

Comment: @KalimulHaq Do you mean something like this `this.restProvider.postData("http://apiurl.com/list", data).then((result : any) => {`

Comment: @KalimulHaq It worked. Thanks.